# Generating tests for REST API based on RAML

Tags: automated-testing, regression-testing, rest-api

I'm trying to find a way to do automated regression testing on a REST API. My idea is to generate automated tests based on the RAML documentation of the API and this way I can also test the consistency of the RAML documentation with the API itself.

Is there a testing tool that uses the RAML documentation for testing purposes?

Does it make sense to try to use the RAML documentation in an automatic way?

Any suggestions regarding the appropriate testing strategy are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

There is a number of testing tools which support RAML. Officially declared ones you can find at RAML [official site page](https://raml.org/developers/test-your-api) related to API testing with RAML.

There is also a number of articles devoted to testing using raml specs over the internet like [this one](https://dzone.com/articles/testing-generic-rest-apis-with-raml).